# Can I make Entity Associations optional or nullable?

Tags: many-to-many, entity, associations, nullable

I have a Superhero. Superheros can have many weapons. Superheros can have many vehicles.
Superheros can attach their weapons to vehicles, but they shouldn't have to.

http://fm001-forumimages.s3.amazonaws.com/EntityHero.png

In the Entity Framework, if I create a weapon and assign it to a Superhero, it also forces me to attach it to a vehicle (error below).

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. What's the correct Entity Association mapping between Superhero, Weapon, and Vehicle?
3. What's a good sample Google search phrase to understand this better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a many to many relation on the weapons to superheroes and weapons to vehicles. It'd be likely expressed as a pair of linking tables, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SuperheroWeapons (
    SuperheroId bigint NOT NULL,
    WeaponId bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SuperheroWeapons_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SuperheroId ASC, WeaponId ASC),
    CONSTRAINT SuperheroWeapons_FK_SuperheroId FOREIGN KEY (SuperheroId) REFERENCES Superheros (SuperheroId),
    CONSTRAINT SuperheroWeapons_FK_WeaponId FOREIGN KEY (WeaponId) REFERENCES Weapons (WeaponId)
)
```

and similar for the VehicleWeapons table.

Answer (score 1):

Your Entity framework relationship between Weapons and Vehicles is off as well as superheros and weapons.

You'll want to make it a many to many relationship, ie. There are many vehicles with many weapons, and there also are many weapons that belong to many vehicles.

You can accomplish this with an intermediary entity one that maps to both weapons and vehicles and superhero and weapons.
take a look at [Many to Many Relationships with EF](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/08/21/many-to-many-mappings-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: I think your help led me to the answer, which wasn't your answer, but it got me there. The foreign keys were Nullable=False, which is a good thing, which precluded me from saving to the database without creating a valid association. So, I'm having to come up with an alternative- I know setting Foreign Keys Nullable=True is probably no good practice. I don't always want a vehicle to have a weapon, so I'm not sure how to not enforce the association.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have foreign keys be nullable, that's actually the way to do it. doing that takes something from a "one to many" relationship to a "zero to many" relationship.